# Effect of Key in component extending React.Component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have created a very basic application, and  try to understand how key behaves in the case of extending `PureComponent` and `Component`.

However from what I found, it seems that when extending PureComponent, this is what I am looking for, using key just skip update b and c, and clearly has a performance boost. But when extending Component, it seems there are no performance gain when key is used [I do not know how to measure performance, here, it just seems to me as the method is called, it should perform at least a bit worse as a bit more code has run].

Here are the code I use for testing:

```js
import React, { Component, PureComponent } from "react";

class Child extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.name}</div>;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount", this.props.name);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update", this.props.name);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("unmount", this.props.name);
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: ["a", "b", "c"],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map(name => {
          return <Child key={name} name={name} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            list: ["b", "c", "d"]
          });
      }, 1000)

  }
}
```

Here are the log for the one extending PureComponent:

```
unmount a
mount d
```

And here are the log for extending Component:

```
unmount a
update b
update c
mount d
```

So my question is

> When using with Component extending `React.Component`, what is the purpose of specifying a key? Can it have any performance gain when we use key in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The `key` prop **has nothing to do** with `Component` vs `PureComponent` comparison.

> The difference between `Component` and `PureComponent` is just that `Component` doesn’t implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`, where `PureComponent` [implements](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) it with shallow comparison.

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed and therefore decide if need to enter a render phase or not.

Refer to [What are Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [Keys Must Only Be Unique Among Siblings](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings).

The result you getting is due to a shallow comparison mentioned above,
try adding the next code to `Child extends Component` to get the same results:

```
// @ class Child extends Component
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps === this.props;
}
```

Results:

```sh
mount a 
mount b 
mount c 
unmount a 
mount d
```

[image: Edit Q-58707167-PureVsNot]

Comment: I know key must be unique, and help React to identify which items have changed. But does this help improving performance in teh case where the component extends React.Component? As if I use `PureComponent`, using key and without key make a difference, while extends `Component` do not.

Comment: Like said, its because `shouldComponentUpdate`, I added an example

Answer (score 0):

Key is basically used to identify an element in React by the unique id due to which rendering can be optimized. As you can see in your example only, React determined that the other two elements need not be changed. Without the key, it would have unmounted all the elements and then re-rendered them on the screen which is not optimized.